# Bash parameter expansion delimiter

Tags: bash, parameters

I'm trying to get `1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10` using parameter expansion `{1..10}` and pattern matching:

```
$ var=$(echo {1..10})
$ echo ${var// /:}
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
```

Is there a more elegant way (one-liner) to do this?

Comment: instead of `read var` I would use `var=$(echo {1..10})`

Comment: My preferred way is `echo {1..10}|sed 's/ /:/g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreeing with @choroba's comment about elegance, here are some other beholdables:

```
# seq is a gnu core utility
seq 1 10 | paste -sd:
# Or:
seq -s: 1 10

# {1..10} is bash-specific
printf "%d\n" {1..10} | paste -sd:

# posix compliant
yes | head -n10 | grep -n . | cut -d: -f1 | paste -sd:
```

Comment: Note that the most portable way to use `paste` on stdin is with the `-` parameter (e.g. BSD paste under mac needs it). I.e. `paste -sd: -`

Comment: Another POSIX solution using a single external call: `awk 'BEGIN { o = 1; for (i=2; i<11; i++) o = o ":" i; print o }'` and here's a POSIX solution that does not need any external calls at all: `i=1 o=1; while [ $i -le 9 ]; do o=$o:$((i+=1)); done; echo $o`

Answer (score 11):

Elegance is in the eye of the beholder:

```
( set {1..10} ; IFS=: ; echo "$*" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
echo {1..9}: 10 | tr -d ' '
```