# Change separator/delim in bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

#### Premise

I realise this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720453/bash-parameter-expansion-delimiter) already exists, but the solutions are not actually changing the delimiter. I would like to know if there is anyway to change the delimiter or if anybody knows where it resides.

---

#### Example

Say i need to pass this string to a program, delimited by commas as that is what the program accepts

```
echo \"abc" "{def,ghi}\"
```

prints

```
"abc def" "abc ghi"
```

where i would want

```
"abc def","abc ghi"
```

Obviously this is just a simple example though.

---

#### What i have tried

Nothing as i have no idea where to look for this delimiter, although i have searched pretty extensively

Also as a sub question:

Using choroba's answer from the other question creates errors when trying to use it to pass it to my script. Admittedly i haven't tried for long though

I tried

```
./script ( set abc" "{def,ghi} ; IFS=: ; echo "$*" )
./script < <( set abc" "{def,ghi} ; IFS=: ; echo "$*" )
./scipt $(( set abc" "{def,ghi} ; IFS=: ; echo "$*" ))
```

Comment: Using `printf` you can say `printf "%s," \"abc" "{def,ghi}\"` and you'll get `"abc def","abc ghi",`. But this is just an idea.

Comment: This worked for me: `(set \"abc\ {def,ghi}\"; IFS=,; echo "$*")`
 prints: `"abc def","abc ghi"`.

Comment: @fedorqui Unfortunately that leaves a trailing comma :(

Comment: @RedX Please read the question.

Comment: @fedorqui Did you mean to comment on this ? I'm not storing any commands, nor using any variables. I just want to be able to change the delimiter in brace expansion so i can use it with my custom script, preferably in a way that allows embedded spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So my test script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$@"
```

And it works fine with:

```
./my_script.sh $(set \"abc\ {def,ghi}\"; IFS=,; echo "$*")
```

It outputs:

```
"abc def","abc ghi"
```

I guess you were missing the `$` to invoke the subshell.

**Updated for main question (whether there is an option to change the separator):**

After looking into bash v4.3 source:

When doing

```
./my_script.sh \"abc\ {1,2}\"
```

there is no way of adding any other separator because there is no separator. The command gets two arguments passed to it `"abc 1"` and `"abc 2"`.

The case of

```
echo \"abc\ {1,2}\"
```

You would need to expand the built-in echo to have either an option or global variable to set the words separator. Currently this is done by `putchar(' ')` in `echo_builtin` in `builtins/echo.def:192`

Comment: I'm gonna upvote this because it answered the sub question but my main question still needs answering. I probably shouldn't have added that at the end, my fault.

Comment: @User112638726 Ok I though, the problem below was exactly the use case for your problem. If your use-case is a different one, post that and maybe we can solve that too. I will look into the source-code of bash to see if there is another way of solving this.

Comment: I'm also looking through to see if i can find anything, If  i do I'll let you know :)